# BPEL:Unable to invoke endpoint uri : 415 unsupported media type

Tags: web-services, rest, soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I'm trying to invoke a HTTP Binding with POST where the endpoint is a RESTFUL webservice that takes in an XML message and sends an email.
I'm using JDeveloper 11g to create the composite where it'll have an exposed HTTP Binding POST and an external reference which is also a HTTP Binding POST that calls a RESTFUL Webservice endpoint . In the BPEL process, i'm just doing a simple receive from the exposed HTTP Binding and then using the input to invoke the External References HTTP Binding.  However, I'm always getting an error at the invoke phase :

> oracle.fabric.common.FabricInvocationException: Unable to invoke
>   endpoint URI  successfully due to: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException:
>   javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Bad response: 415 Unsupported Media Type
>   from url
>
> Unable to invoke endpoint URI  successfully due to:
>   javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Bad
>   response: 415 Unsupported Media Type from url

I'm guessing that it's because my payload is lacking the MIME header content-type : application/xml. The webservice endpoint itself is working fine as I'm able to test it through other means such as POSTMan and soapUI.

Is there a way to set the HTTP header content-type of the payload? Is there anyway to check or verify? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Mark

Comment: Do you have WADL for this restful webservice? What's your client look like? Show us your client code which you are using to invoke this post method.

Comment: Hi, I do not have WADL for this webservice. There isn't a client code that invokes the post method. 

The endpoint uri will take in an XML message that has been sent using HTTP POST which contains information such as subject title and user name and extract the values to send an email. The webservice endpoint uri itself is working fine as i'm able to sent an xml message with apps like POSTMAN and SOAPUI and get a proper response back.

However when testing the bpel process, it fails at the invoke activity. My initial guess is that the header content-type is not set to application/xml

Comment: I am not familiar with BPEL, but from your error, your guess is correct your bpel process in not able to receive MIME content. There should be some properties to set it. Hope someone with BPEL knowledge would jump in for your query.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm new to BPEL myself so I'm not too sure where and how to set/verify this.